# Does asymptotic expansion of Whittaker function $W_{\lambda , \mu}(z)$ exist for $|\lambda| \to 0$?

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions

Suppose Whittaker function
$$
\tag 1 W_{\lambda , \mu}(z)
$$
Does some asymptotic expansion exist for the case $|\lambda| \to 0$? I'm interested not in the case of $\lambda = 0$, but in the case of small imaginary $\lambda$.

Comment: Here is what they are: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_function

Comment: @martycohen : but I don't see asymptotic expansions for $\lambda \to 0$.

Comment: It suffices to (Taylor :) expand.

Comment: @Startwearingpurple : but how? I need to get the uniform expansion...